# What is sampling error?

Tags: sampling, error

I'm curious as to what the exact definition of sampling error is.

If someone says the sampling error is 3% what exactly does that mean?

Is one standard deviation 3%, or is there some other definition?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the sampling error refers to the inherent uncertainty due to the sampling process. E.g. when you ask a sample of a total population (and get answers from everyone), your uncertainty comes from not asking everyone and exactly how you randomly picked (the sampling process) the people to ask.

In the context you mention, I would normally understand it to be the standard error of an estimate of a percentage. When you are not too close to 0% or 100%, and have asked enough people, then the sampling error will be approximately symmetrical around the estimate and the results can be meaningfully expressed as estimate $\pm$ standard error.